# Android: Save State of Radio Buttons

Tags: android, radio-button, save

Hi I'm trying to create an app for Android and in order to develop it i need to navigate through different pages and questions. For this task I have defined a radiogroup with some radiobuttons. What I want to obtain is each question answered radiobutton and when the user goes thorugh differentes pages the value can be retrieved. I have tried this code that consists of that if there is one selected radiobutton, there arent created new radiobuttons (radiobuttons checked false). However with this code, there is always a selected answer so there is always the same radiobutton selected. I will appreciate some help.

```
        radBotA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioCheckChangeListener);
            radBotB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioCheckChangeListener);
            radBotC.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioCheckChangeListener);
            radBotD.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioCheckChangeListener);
            radBotA.setOnClickListener(radioClickListener);
            radBotB.setOnClickListener(radioClickListener);
            radBotC.setOnClickListener(radioClickListener);
            radBotD.setOnClickListener(radioClickListener);
            if (radBotA.isChecked()){
                Answers[position]="A";
                }
            else if(radBotB.isChecked()){
           Answers[position]="B"; }            
            else if(radBotB.isChecked()){
                   Answers[position]="C"; } 
            else if(radBotC.isChecked()){
                   Answers[position]="D"; }     
            else if(radBotD.isChecked()){
                   Answers[position]="D"; } 
            else {
                radBotA.setChecked(false);
                radBotA.setChecked(false);
                radBotA.setChecked(false);
                radBotA.setChecked(false);
            }

        bPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                position = position -1; 
                questions.Previous();
                currentQuestion();







            }
        });
        bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {
                position = position +1;
                questions.Next();       
                currentQuestion();





            }
        });

    private void currentQuestion() {
            if (position==0){
                bPrevious.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                    bPrevious.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            if (position==nPreguntas-1){
                bNext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                bNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } 
            questions.currentQuestion(this, category);
            enunciado.setImageResource(Enunciado[position]);
            pregunta.setText(questions.getPregunta());
            final RadioButton radBotA = new RadioButton(this);
            final RadioButton radBotB = new RadioButton(this);
            final RadioButton radBotC = new RadioButton(this);
            final RadioButton radBotD = new RadioButton(this);

            radBotA.setText("A. " + questions.getRespuestaA());
            radBotB.setText("B. " + questions.getRespuestaB());
            radBotC.setText("C. " + questions.getRespuestaC());
            radBotD.setText("D. " + questions.getRespuestaD());
            String nprueba = "Item " +  questions.getId() + " de "+ nPreguntas;


            NombrePrueba.setText(nprueba);
            if (radBotA.isChecked()){
                Answers[position]="A";
                }
            else if(radBotB.isChecked()){
           Answers[position]="B"; }            
            else if(radBotB.isChecked()){
                   Answers[position]="C"; } 
            else if(radBotC.isChecked()){
                   Answers[position]="D"; }     
            else if(radBotD.isChecked()){
                   Answers[position]="D"; } 
            else {
                radBotA.setChecked(false);
                radBotA.setChecked(false);
                radBotA.setChecked(false);
                radBotA.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
```

thank you all for your time

Edit:

```
public void save(){
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Answers", 0); 
              SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();


            e.putBoolean("A0",radBotA.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("B0",radBotB.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("C0",radBotC.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("D0",radBotD.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("A1",radBotA.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("B1",radBotB.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("C1",radBotC.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("D1",radBotD.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("A2",radBotA.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("B2",radBotB.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("C2",radBotC.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("D2",radBotD.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("A3",radBotA.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("B3",radBotB.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("C3",radBotC.isChecked());
            e.putBoolean("D3",radBotD.isChecked());
public void load(){
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Answers", 0);
              boolean answerA0 = settings.getBoolean("A0", false); 
              boolean answerB0 = settings.getBoolean("B0", false);
              boolean answerC0 = settings.getBoolean("C0", false);
              boolean answerD0 = settings.getBoolean("D0", false);
              boolean answerA1 = settings.getBoolean("A1", false); 
              boolean answerB1 = settings.getBoolean("B1", false);
              boolean answerC1 = settings.getBoolean("C1", false);
              boolean answerD1 = settings.getBoolean("D1", false);
              boolean answerA2 = settings.getBoolean("A2", false); 
              boolean answerB2 = settings.getBoolean("B2", false);
              boolean answerC2 = settings.getBoolean("C2", false);
              boolean answerD2 = settings.getBoolean("D2", false);
              boolean answerA3 = settings.getBoolean("A3", false); 
              boolean answerB3 = settings.getBoolean("B3", false);
              boolean answerC3 = settings.getBoolean("C3", false);
              boolean answerD3 = settings.getBoolean("D3", false);
```

However I don't know how to continue. I v' thinking about the following code but it gives me error and where posicion is the "Page Number":

```
public void Test(){
        switch(posicion){
            case(0):
                if(answerA0==true){
                    e.putBoolean("A0",radBotA.isChecked());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, according to your edit, you are missing `e.commit();` part, which should be put after you finish writing data to your editor. Otherwise, your data will not be stored in `SharedPreferences`. 

And if it goes about this second part, I don't really know what you meant by this `Test()` method. Please, explain what should this `Test()` method do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to retrieve some data in other activities. In that case the easiest way would be to use `SharedPreferences`.

After user answers the question (`CheckBox`'s check state is being changed) you should store your information in `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Answers", 0); // first argument is just a name of your SharedPreferences which you want to use. It's up to you how you will name it, but you have to use the same name later when you want to retrieve data.
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("questionA", radBotA.isChecked()); // first argument is a name of a data that you will later use to retrieve it and the second argument is a value that will be stored
  editor.putBoolean("questionB", radBotB.isChecked());
  editor.putBoolean("questionC", radBotC.isChecked());
  editor.putBoolean("questionD", radBotD.isChecked());

  editor.commit(); // Commit the changes
```

So now you have those information stored in your internal storage. In other activity, you can retrieve this information:

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Answers", 0);
  boolean answerA = settings.getBoolean("questionA", false); // The second argument is a default value, if value with name "questionA" will not be found
  boolean answerB = settings.getBoolean("questionB", false);
  boolean answerC = settings.getBoolean("questionC", false);
  boolean answerD = settings.getBoolean("questionD", false);
```

Comment: Thank you Mosquito I'll try your solution, the issue is that all those questions are answered at the same activity so the 4 radioButtons are the same.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same activity, but I don't see any problem here. You have access to those `CheckBox`es, so you can store their state in `SharedPreferences`. Actually I see that each of your questions contains 4 answers (`CheckBox`es). Am I right? If so, I'll edit my answer so that it will better suit your problem.

Comment: Yes, they are at the same activity and i dont know if it is important but instead of checkboxes they are RadioButtons. Tnak you again

Comment: Still need a bit more information - in one activity you have only ONE question with 4 `RadioButton`s or there are MORE THAN ONE questions in one activity?

Comment: There are more than one questions in the same activity with 4 radiobuttons each question

Comment: But you know the number of those questions, thus you know the number of radiobuttons. So that instead of naming them "questionA", "questionB", etc. while putting their states into `SharedPreferences`, you can have something like "questionA1", "questionA2", "questionA3", "questionA4", "questionB1", "questionB2", and so on, where A, B, C, D is a number of question and 1, 2, 3, 4 is a number of answer in this question. Is it clear?

Comment: Ok, gonna try this , Mosquito, Thank you very much for information and time

Comment: Hi again Mosquito. I have been the things you asked but however i dont know very well how to implement this. I show you what I have done but I dont know well what to do I edited first answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on same application and the solution is that you have to store state of Radio button according to your question Number and for each question there is different key, like this:

```
final RadioButton rdSelection=(RadioButton)findViewById(mradioOptGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
int child_index=mradioOptGroup.indexOfChild(rdSelection);

switch(mid)
{
    case 1: 
        sharedpreferences.putint("",child_index);
        break;
    case 2:
       sharedpreferences.putint("",child_index);
       break;
}
```

and do like this for all your questions on every next question

and on every previous question you have to store state of radio button of `mid+1`

where `mid` is your question number

Answer (score 0):

i just solved this problem , now i am able to save the current state of radio button on every next click and on every previous click i get back the radio state,even at the if the user changed the state by going to previous question or any of the question.